# (CSS/HTML) How can i make this alignment in Bootstrap? (Left Text right image Grid)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, box

Im looking for help .. how can I make this box in Bootstrap with the Gridsystem?
[The Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/750tu.png)
Left centered Text and right Image like this?
The Second Question is .. how can I make that the image go to the background when the size of the Browser is smaller.. like on the Image
[Image in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z02pn.png)

Example: gumpyframework
Tried:

```html
        <div class="row text-center">
          <h2>Team</h2>
          <hr class="small">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <p>Test Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/test.png" id="africaPhoto" alt="Smiley face" width="80%">                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show your workings so far?

Comment: Added code snipped .. what i have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty much inspect any bootstrap website and find that html layout. You should also read the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com) it explains how the grid system works and how to properly utilise it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1 class="text-info">
    Become a Surgeon!
    </h1>
    <p>Digital Surgeons is looking for an experienced web developer ....</p>
    <button class="btn btn-info">
    Apply Now
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><img class="hidden-xs" src="http://placehold.it/500x500" id="africaPhoto" alt="Smiley face" >                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

To answer your second question, you can use the classes hidden-xs or hidden-sm to hide the image on smaller screen sizes likewise you can also use visible-xs to only show an element on a particular screen size you can also use custom classes such as media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zcp5o6f0/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the image as `background-image` on the whole section to properly display the image. You can move the image around using the `background-position` property. See the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for more information.

```css
.section {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/gowMz8A.jpg');
  background-position: right center;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum modi tenetur incidunt eveniet? Ut nesciunt ipsum, nulla nobis mollitia nemo tempora, architecto aliquid voluptatem vero maxime! Dolorem dolore natus delectus.

    </div>
  </div>

  
</section>
```